# Clojure bigdec division rules

Tags: clojure, bigdecimal, arbitrary-precision

I am hitting a floating-precision problem : one of my results of dividing between `Doubles` and/or `Long` gives me `2.8421709430404007E-14` instead of `0`.

So I guess I have to use `BigDecimals` ([`bigdec`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bigdec) more precisely).

My question is :

- will operations involving a `bigdec` convert all other numbers involved in the operation to a suitable type ?
- is there an operation that does that ? I am basically looking for the equivalent of [`*'`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*'), but `/'` doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. If you use any doubles (or floats) in your computation, the final result will be a double.
2. Otherwise any computation involving `BigDecimal`s will return a `BigDecimal` result or throw an exception.
3. Exceptions might be thrown if the result cannot be represented exactly, if some intermediate computation causes long overflow, or if you divide by zero.
4. `+'` etc. promote to `BigInteger` where `+` would cause integer overflow.
5. Rounding can be introduced to deal with exact representation issues – see `(doc with-precision)`.

Comment: Thanks ! Regarding (1), I don't mind the result being a double (I guess 0 can be represented as a double), but I am worried about the internal steps (ie. I don't want to get something very close to zero instead of 0). Does this mean that in my case I should use exclusively `bigdec` ?

Comment: Using doubles places a limit on the precision of your computations. In particular, getting a value close, but not exactly equal to the ideal / theoretical value of the your computation interpreted with unlimited precision is expected. If that is unacceptable, you can use `BigDecimal`s for (way, way) slower arithmetic with precision under your control. You won't get unlimited precision for arbitrary computations anyway (because of infinite decimal expansions – e.g. `(/ 1M 3M)`), but at least you can set your own precision parameters. Ratios are a another option (slower, more precision – `1/3`).

Comment: The short of it is that if you need the precision guarantees of bigdec, you'll need to avoid doubles, yes. You should also read the docstring of `with-precision` and use it if you run into infinite expansion problems. And if you don't care about performance too much (you have a computation that can be slow, but really needs to be extremely precise), then Ratios might be worth a shot.